# Feature selection of non stationary data

Tags: feature-selection, stationarity, feature-engineering, spectral-analysis

I am working with EEG signals which are non-stationary. I have used spectrogram to analyse the data in specific frequecies. I have to select some features from the specific-frequency time signals inorder to reduce  its dimension and use it for classification.

I cannot use PCA as it works only for stationary signals. Is there a method of feature selection which can be used for these signals which are non-stationary in  nature?

Comment: What is your final aim? Is it to classify EEG signals? Can you determine for each EEG the amplitudes at different frequencies?

Comment: @rnso Yes my aim is to classify the EEG signals and I can determine the amplitudes at different frequencies. But since the signal is non-stationary, the power of the signal changes with frequency as well as time. Spectrogram is able to capture this entire information. I somehow want to select a small number of features from the spectrogram and use them in a classifier